# How to change the dialog modal box backgrounds

Tags: 2013

I want to change the background colour of the modal pop up boxes that appear when you are making some kind of edits to the site that need to be processed, ie: there is a normally a pop indicating "working on it" with a spinnner icon that animates.

At the moment the box surrounding that text is transparent and the blue text is appearing over a blue background I have customised, which is difficult to see, so I want to bring back the white box so the text stands out more, How would I do this with css?

Dean

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following css:

```
.ms-dialog .ms-core-overlay {
    background: #fff !important;
}
div.ms-dlgContent {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

If the above doesn't work, you need to override the css class for dialog that you customized with your background. To override dialog css, prepend your class with '.ms-dialog'

Comment: Hi Aveenav, Thanks for that suggestion I will try that out and let you know how I get on with that,  I should of added in my original post that this is for a sharepoint 2013 site, are those 2013 based classes?

Comment: yes, it's for SP 2013, should work for 2016 too.